# Azure DevOps: Is it possible to consume a variable inside a function, inside a template?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

**My scenario:**

*azure-pipelines.yml:*

```
variables:
  - name: service
    value: Foo

jobs:
  - job:
    steps:
      - template: consume-variable.yml
```

*consume-variable.yml:*

```
steps:
  - task: Bash@3
    displayName: "Echo $(service) in lowercase"
    inputs:
      targetType: inline
      script: echo ${{ lower(service) }}
```

**What I expect:**

The displayName is resolved as `Echo Foo in lowercase`, and the script as `echo foo`.

**What happens:**

The displayName is resolved correctly, but the variable inside the `lower()` function is not resolved and throws an error.

**What I have tried:**

It is clear that calling the variable outside a function works, as I can use `$(service)` by itself anywhere (such as the displayName above). But I cannot figure out if there is a syntax that will resolve correctly inside a *function*. I have tried all combinations I know of, such as `variables.service`, `variables[service]`, using `[]` instead of `{{}}`, etc.

I know I can pass a parameter to the template and that will resolve correctly. But I specifically want to know if there is a way to use a variable instead of a parameter here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable will not be accessible at the point that the expression is trying to access it. You can get around this by parsing your variable to the template as a parameter, and then referencing the parameter in your template.

See below example:

main.yml:

```
variables:
- name: service
  value: Foo

jobs:
- job:
  steps:
  - template: consume-variable.yml
    parameters:
      service: ${{ variables.service }}
```

consume.variable.yml:

```
parameters:
- name: service

steps:
- task: Bash@3
  displayName: "Echo $(service) in lowercase"
  inputs:
    targetType: inline
    script: echo ${{ lower(parameters.service) }}
```

Output:

```
Starting: Echo Foo in lowercase
==============================================================================
Task         : Bash
Description  : Run a Bash script on macOS, Linux, or Windows
Version      : 3.231.5
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/bash
==============================================================================
Generating script.
Script contents:
echo foo
========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
/usr/bin/bash /home/vsts/work/_temp/ef0ad848-6b0b-4bbd-8601-7e3a200b3091.sh
foo

Finishing: Echo Foo in lowercase
```

Comment: Yes, it does seem that using parameters is the only way for a function to use a value inside a template. Thank you for confirming!

Answer (score 2):

As another workaround to avoid the template expression in the script from being processed during template expansion, you may define a new variable with `lower` function and use macro syntax of this variable in the template script. Here is a sample for your reference.

###### /YAML/azure-pipelines.yml:

```
variables:
  - name: service
    value: Foo
  - name: servceLower
    value: ${{ lower(variables['service']) }}
steps:
- template: ../TEMPLATE/consume-variable.yml
```

###### /TEMPLATE/consume-variable.yml

```
steps:
  - task: Bash@3
    displayName: "Echo $(service) in lowercase"
    inputs:
      targetType: inline
      script: |
        echo "service is $(service)"
        echo "serviceLower is $(serviceLower)"
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer! This is also a good approach. I am slightly leaning towards Parameters just for code cleanness, but this seems to work equally well. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Custom variables are inaccessible at that moment: [How can I use variables inside of templates?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops&pivots=templates-includes#how-can-i-use-variables-inside-of-templates)

> There are times when it may be useful to set parameters to values
> based on variables. Parameters are expanded early in processing a
> pipeline run so not all variables are available. To see what
> predefined variables are available in templates, see Use predefined
> variables.

Try to use parameters: [Template parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/template-parameters?view=azure-devops)

Comment: Thank you for sharing the (not super clear, I must say) documentation where MS confirms that these values will not be available yet at that point in the run. Confirms what I suspected all along!

Answer (score 1):

It’s best to keep your template script `consume-variable.yml` as simple as possible, and pass in the needed + simplest parameters.

`azure-pipelines.yml`

```
variables:
  - name: service
    value: Foo

jobs:
  - job: "test"
    steps:
      - template: consume-variable.yml
        parameters:
          param1: ${{ lower(variables.service) }}
```

`consume-variable.yml`

```
parameters:
- name: param1
  type: string

steps:
- task: Bash@3
  displayName: "Echo $(service) in lowercase using param"
  inputs:
    targetType: inline
    script: echo ${{ parameters.param1 }}
```

Comment: Yes, it appears parameters is the way to go. Thank you for confirming!